# Sendto returning random values

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I call sendto in my udp socket client side like this:

```
if((num_w = sendto(cli_udp_sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr) )) < 0)
```

but there seems to be no nothing received at the server side and in very strange fashion, num_w, when printed out, gives values like:

-197379208
-1440076936
2054978424

And perror() displays "success"

Client code up till that point:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>       /*  socket definitions        */
#include <sys/types.h>        /*  socket types              */
#include <arpa/inet.h>        /*  inet (3) funtions         */
#include <unistd.h>           /*  misc. UNIX functions      */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
/*  Global constants  */

#define MAX_LINE           (1000)
#define LISTENQ (10)

/*  Function declarations  */
int ParseCmdLine(int argc, char *argv[], char **szPort, char **szAddress, char ** serv_udp_port);



/*  main()  */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    //
short int cli_port;                  /*  port number               */
short int serv_port;
struct    sockaddr_in servaddr;  /*  socket address structure  */
socklen_t serv_addrlen = sizeof(servaddr);
struct    sockaddr_in cliaddr;
char      buffer[MAX_LINE];      /*  character buffer          */
char     *szAddress;             /*  Holds remote IP address   */
char     *szPort;                /*  Holds remote port         */
char     *serv_udp_port;
char     *endptr;                /*  for strtol()              */
int cli_udp_sock;
/*  Get command line arguments  */

ParseCmdLine(argc, argv, &szPort, &szAddress, &serv_udp_port);


/*  Set the remote port */ 

cli_port = strtol(szPort, &endptr, 0);
serv_port = strtol(serv_udp_port, &endptr, 0);

if ( *endptr ) 
{
    printf("ECHOCLNT: Invalid port supplied.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}



/*  Set all bytes in socket address structure to zero, and fill in the relevant data members   */

memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr));
cliaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
cliaddr.sin_port        = htons(cli_port);
cliaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_port        = htons(serv_port);

/*  Set the remote IP address  */

if ( inet_aton(argv[2], &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0 ) 
{
    printf("ECHOCLNT: Invalid remote IP address.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int list_s;
if ( (list_s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 ) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ECHOCLNT: Error creating listening socket.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (listen(list_s, LISTENQ) < 0)
{
    printf("Failed to called listen.\n");
}
if( ((cli_udp_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0) )< 0))
{
    printf("UDP socket was not successfully created. Exiting...\n");
    exit(0);
}

//if(bind(cli_udp_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr)) > 0); 

char command[100];
    /*  Get command from user  */
printf("==============================================\n");

do
{     
    if(strcmp(command, "s\n") == 0)
    {
        printf("______________________________________________\n");
            printf("'s' entered, \nEnter the string to request\n"); //prompt for string to enter
            strcpy(buffer, "CAP\n");                //set first set of characteres to CAP\n
            char bucket[100];                   //space for entered string
            fgets(bucket, sizeof bucket, stdin);
        printf("The string entered is: %s", bucket);
            strcat(buffer, bucket);

            /*  Send string to echo server, and retrieve response  */
            int num_w;
        if((num_w = sendto(cli_udp_sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr) )) < 0)
        {
            perror("error: ");
            printf("Problem writing data to server, errno: %d", errno);
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            perror("error 2: ");
            printf("num_w: %d\n");
        }
```

Thanks so much in advance!
(Oh and I'm on Kali linux, virtual machine, Windows 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't printing `num_w`. You've left it out of the `printf()` statement. You're just printing whatever random junk is on the stack.

> And `perror()` displays "success"

So `num_w` was positive. Calling `perror()` in that case is pointless.

Comment: thanks! funny oversight with num_w.. Apart from that my server doesn't seem to be receiving any kind of data, can you see a reason whythis might be from my client program?

Comment: Well for a start `servaddr` doesn't contain an IP address, only INADDR_ANY (all zeroes), so you are broadcasting, which may not get out of your localhost. You also haven't bound `list_s`, so it's surprising that the `listen()` succeeded, and a program that contains `listen()` is a server, not a client.

Comment: thanks again! I'm aware that its the server that usually listens, the listening socket is only there as because it was required..for now, I'm not doing anything with the tcp socket..I just want to get the udp socket to work. Shouldn't the line:if ( inet_aton(argv[2], &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0 )  not assign the second argument in my command line invocation of my client to servaddr as an ip address?

Comment: Yes it should, I missed that. You'll have to provide the server code.